# Plotly: How to modify hovertemplate of a histogram?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to modify the hovertemplate of a plotly histogram. So far, couldn't find a way to:
Round the values given
Remove the name of the histograms (here: '2012', '2013')
Add a name to indicate what the values represent

Desired hovertext:

```
Bin-range: -1.24, 3.31
```

or

Even better alternative (range with hyphen):

```
Bin-range: -1.24 - 3.31
```

Any ideas?

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'2012': np.random.randn(200),
                   '2013': np.random.randn(200)+1})

fig = ff.create_distplot([df[c] for c in df.columns], 
                         df.columns, bin_size=.25, show_rug=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: `create_displot` is deprecated. https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_distplot.html and does not support hovertext like other plotly functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The answer:

Adding the following snippet to your setup will produce the plot below:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='<i>Bin-range</i>:' + '%{x}' + '<extra></extra>',
                  selector=dict(type="histogram"))
```

The part `selector=dict(type="histogram")` is there to only update the histogram traces and leave the lines alone. The `'<extra></extra>'` part is as cool as it is cryptic, and simply removes `2012` and `2013` from the hoverlabels.

[image]

I hope this comes close to what you want to achieve. I'll have to take a closer look at the rounding part though. But all in all I think the plot looks pretty good as it is

#### Some details and comments:

To my knowledge, and contrary to the statements on github on [plotly.figure_factory.create_distplot](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_distplot.html), `ff.create_distplot` is in fact not headed towards deprecation. It's just not being updated anymore. Further, it appears that `ff.create_distplot` still is the best alternative for creating hisograms with a normal distribution or kde estimation added to it. So it's not going anywhere in the foreseeable future.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'2012': np.random.randn(200),
                   '2013': np.random.randn(200)+1})

fig = ff.create_distplot([df[c] for c in df.columns], 
                         df.columns, bin_size=.25, show_rug=False)

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='<i>Bin-range</i>:' + '%{x}' + '<extra></extra>',
                  selector=dict(type="histogram"))

#fig.update_layout(hoverinfo = 'x+y+text')

fig.show()
```