# Change y-axis title hover in histogram plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, plotly-python

I would like to change the y-axis title of a histogram in plotly python. We could use the `fig.update_layout(yaxis_title="New y-axis title")` to change the title of the y-axis. But this doesn't automatically change the hover title of the y-axis. We could use the `labels` argument to change the title of the x-axis and hover title but this doesn't work for the y-axis title with count. Here is some reproducible code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill",
                  labels={"total_bill": "Total bill"})
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title="New y-axis title")
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the y-axis title is nicely changed, but the hover title isn't changed. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you can modify [@vestland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928453/4819376)'s solution here.

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill",
                  labels={"total_bill": "Total bill"})
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='Total bill=' + '%{x}' + '<br>'
                  'New y-axis title=' + '%{y}',
                  selector=dict(type="histogram"))
fig.show()
```

Or instead of `update_traces` just

```py
fig.data[0]["hovertemplate"] = fig.data[0]["hovertemplate"]\
    .replace("count", "New y-axis title")
```